# add tab bar without tab bar controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I need to add an tab bar in my view with out tab bar controller, because in my `prepareForSegue` function I pass data to my view whitch contains the tab bar.

I add the tab bar from the object library with its items, and in my view class I add UITabBarDelegate.
my code is like this:

```
class SchedaCompletaVC: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

var event:Event! // data passing from prepareforsegue

@IBOutlet var mainTabBar:UITabBar!
var descrizioneTab:UIViewController! //if i click on first tab, so my default view 
var mappaTab:UIViewController! // second tab

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("event \(event.eventId)")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    switch (item.tag) {
    case 1:
        self.view.insertSubview(descrizioneTab.view.belowSubview(mainTabBar)) //here I had error
       break;
    case 2:
        //if second tab is selected
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I got this code from an [tutorial](http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/) whitch is for objective-c, I tried to convert it in swift.

My code doesn't work, I don't know what to do?

Please help. Thank you!

Update:
my storyboard is like this: [image]

Comment: what exactly does _"My code doesn't work"_ mean?

Comment: your attempt to convert the linked code to _Swift_ is half-done only... are you really wondering it does not work?

Comment: I'm new in programming, could you tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the swift version :-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTabBar: UITabBar!

    var viewController1: UIViewController?
    var viewController2: UIViewController?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

        switch item.tag {

        case 1:
            if viewController1 == nil {

                var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        }
            self.view.insertSubview(viewController1!.view!, belowSubview: self.mainTabBar)
            break


        case 2:
            if viewController2 == nil {

                var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        }
            self.view.insertSubview(viewController2!.view!, belowSubview: self.mainTabBar)
            break

        default:
            break

        }


    }


}
```

Then you should click the UITabBarItem & ctrl drag it to viewcontroller and click delegate.

Tag for Tab Bar Item( for first tab item tag is 1, for second tab item, tag is 2)

StoryBoard identifier for ViewController(ViewController1 and ViewController2, Respectively)

Comment: Is there any way to implement this without creating a new instance of the view controllers each time?

Answer (score 2):

I have an Objective-C solution. It works fine, you may convert it into Swift.

ViewController.h file code

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *mainTabBar;

        @end
```

ViewController.m file

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
            #import "MyFirstTabViewController.h"
            #import "MySecondTabViewController.h"
            @interface ViewController ()
            {
                UIViewController *viewController1;
                UIViewController *viewController2;
            }

            @end

            @implementation ViewController

            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                self.mainTabBar.delegate=self;
            }


            - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {



                switch (item.tag) {
                    case 1:
                        if (viewController1 == nil) {
                            viewController1 =
                            [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                       bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];

                        }
                        [self.view insertSubview:viewController1.view belowSubview:self.mainTabBar];

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (viewController2 == nil) {
                            viewController2 =
                            [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                       bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];

                        }
                        [self.view insertSubview:viewController2.view belowSubview:self.mainTabBar];

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }


            - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
            {
                [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }

            @end
```

Do not Forget.

1) Tag for Tab Bar Item( for first tab item tag is 1, for second tab item, tag is 2)

2) StoryBoard identifier for ViewController(First and  Second, Respectively)

[image: StoryBoard Image]

Comment: are you, using storyboard ?

Comment: i can't understand your problem clearly, can you explain it properly ?