# How to attach view controller to Tab bar without tab bar controller in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am using tab bar view not tab bar controller. please suggest me how to attach the view controllers to the tab bar item. Thank you!!!

Comment: are you try any code or search anything for same ? if you try anything paste code.

Comment: i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267123/add-tab-bar-without-tab-bar-controller-in-swift but it didn't worked